# Updating the column type of a large dataset in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently working on a web visualization using d3. I am not an expert in Javascript, and am looking to learn more. I am having trouble getting my dataset to have the correct column types. I loaded the data with d3.csv:

```
  var data = d3.csv(pathToCsv).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
```

This works, however, it causes all of my values to be strings in my data.

Only the first column should be a string. What I would normally do, is specify the value type of each column manually:

```
    var data = d3.dsv(",","mydata.csv",function(d){

    return{
       name:  d.name,
       value1: +d.value1,
       value2: +d.value2,
```

Unfortunately, this dataset has over 200 columns, so manually specifying the column type like this is not feasible. Is there a way to loop through and apply the above logic to columns, starting at the 2nd column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [autoType](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-autotype). `autoType` will covert all your data types automatically. It tries its best to detect the type automatically for you, but it may have false positives sometimes.

```
 var data = d3.csv(pathToCsv, d3.autoType)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution; I wasn't aware of this function in d3. This works perfectly for my dataset.

Comment: No problem! Be sure to accept the answer if it helped you.